# How this hand should have been played?

Tags: odds

I am playing 1-2 NL Holdem.

I am holding JQ off-suit. There is a raise of $15 by SB. BB calls and i called. Total pot here is $45.

Now there are 3 plays in the game.

Flop comes 9 10 2 rainbow.

The person who raised initially bets $25. BB called and i called.

Turn comes J. The person who raised initially bets $50. BB called and i called.

River comes 3. The person who raised initially checks. BB checks and i checked.

SB shows pocket 10s which gives him trips. BB and i had the same cards (JQo).

How was this hand supposed to be played? Was it wise to call open ended straight after flop? Something i could have done different to give the impression that i am holding something that will beat pocket 10s?

Comment: What is your position? What are the stack sizes?

Comment: How many seats?

Comment: i am in the middle position and there were total 9 people including me on the table. On turn only 3. SB, BB and me.

Comment: OK, the odds of hitting the straight post-flop were about 52% then but I'd still question the pre-flop call.

Comment: @RobbieDee : How did you come up with those percentages? As per my calculation, the percentages were 32% (8 outs * 4 on turn) and 16% (8 outs * 2 on river). I could be wrong but that is how i calculate my percentages.

Comment: 52 - 18 (hole cards) - 3 (flop) leaves 31 cards. Probability on turn for hitting an out card is 8/31. Probability on river for hitting an out card is 8/30. Added together gives 52.47%. In practice you'd be better served looking at the pot odds each betting round rather than raw percentages though.

Comment: Yes - one or more players may hold one or more of your outs. A bit long to go into but a lot of poker is making the best decision on incomplete information. For that reason, you play a lot more starting hands heads up than you would with full ring.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good example that calling in poker is the worst thing you can do. You can't see if your opponent ist bluffing or having a big hand. Because you don't `check` your position by giving him a decision.

First of all calling 7,5 blinds with JQ  offsuit is questionable.

The flop is `good` for you. You are holding 2 overcards and an open endet straight draw.

which means any 8 or any K  gives you a straight and any J or Q will give you the top pair.

But if someone already bet 25 after that flop, top pair wont help i guess.

so it's around 8 cards which are helping you to get the straight. Now it's simple math.

8 from 47 are around 16% and if you don't win you have another chance on river for 8 from 46.

which is 17,02% on turn and than 17,39% on river.

so calling 25 for a pot of 100 you need at least 25% chance and you simply don't have it.

What you missed to do is, to check your position by for example betting something.

If the other player calls you should know that he has a made hand already or sitting at least on a big draw as you do.

Yes i made the math here a  little simple, of course you can also add the chance to get JJ and QQ in the last both cards which is nearly 2% but you are still far away from reaching the % u need to win if you always have this scenario and play endlessly...

small edit :

you  say 9 players on the table, that's maximum or near maximum (some have 9 seats some have 10)  the more people, the less cards you play. Easy as that, your fault was simply to play JQ for 7,5 BB's. And after calling it's hard to throw away, i know...

Comment: Have to agree with Ray. That is a little too much action to be calling with JQo. All you could have done is come over the top pre-flop but that would have been risky given your hand. After seeing the open-ended draw, I can see why you pressed on after this as the odds are generally favourable with the turn and river left.

Answer (score 0):

**Pre**
Did you initially just call. Call the raise is questionable but you had position and and can hit a nutted level hand.

**Flop**
8 outs to straight.  Runner JJ, QQ, JQ is probably good so give yourself 1 more out.  No way you can rep JJ as you should have raised pre.

Hand odds (45-9)/9 = 4.2

Pot odds 95 / 25 =  3.8

Hand odds > pot odds so it not a call but close.  I you can get another bet in if you hit then it is a call.

**Turn**
Turn you pick up 2 more outs so your hands odds = 3.6 and pot odd 4.4 so call.

**River**
Surprised a set just checked.